# Is it possible to use requests to login Linkedin.com?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests, scrape

I'm using Python-requests to scrape data from Linkedin.com. But I met some issue with csrf authentication.

Linkedin.com put csrf-related values on its html file and it's easy to find them, so I imitated [This Stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907503/logging-in-to-linkedin-with-python-requests-sessions%20and) and write this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

import json

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/login/zh-cn?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin'

driver.get(url)

username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username')))
password = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password')))

submit = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app__container"]/main/div[2]/form/div[3]/button')))

loginCsrfParam = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app__container"]/main/div[2]/form/input[9]')
print(loginCsrfParam.get_attribute('value'))

username.send_keys('username@xxx.com')
password.send_keys('password')

time.sleep(1)

submit.click()

cookies = driver.get_cookies()
with open("cookies.txt", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(cookies, fp)

driver.quit()

import requests
from requests.cookies import RequestsCookieJar
import json

from lxml import etree

LINKEDIN_USERNAME = 'username@xxx.com'
LINKEDIN_PASSWORD = 'password'


jar = RequestsCookieJar()

with open("cookies.txt", "r") as fp:
    cookies = json.load(fp)
    for cookie in cookies:
        jar.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

headers = {
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36',
        'Referer':'https://www.linkedin.com/login/zh-cn?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

client = requests.Session()
client.headers = headers
client.cookies = jar

HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/login/zh-cn?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login-submit'

r = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL,cookies=jar)

html = r.content

h = etree.HTML(html)
csrfToken = h.xpath('//*[@id="app__container"]/main/div[2]/form/input[1]/@value') #csrfToken
sIdString = h.xpath('//*[@id="app__container"]/main/div[2]/form/input[3]/@value') #sIdString
loginCsrfParam = h.xpath('//*[@id="app__container"]/main/div[2]/form/input[9]/@value') #loginCsrfParam

login_information = {
'session_key':LINKEDIN_USERNAME,
'session_password':LINKEDIN_PASSWORD,
'loginCsrfParam': loginCsrfParam[0],
'csrfToken':csrfToken[0],
'sIdString':sIdString[0],
'parentPageKey':'d_checkpoint_lg_consumerLogin',
'trk':'guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin',
'controlId':'d_checkpoint_lg_consumerLogin-login_submit_button',
'loginFlow':'REMEMBER_ME_OPTIN'
}

p = client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_information, cookies=jar)

req = client.get('https://www.linkedin.com/feed', cookies=jar)

print(req.text)
```

However, the script didn't work. "print(req.text)" didn't return a logged-in Linkedin site, instead, the return html looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm2t6.png)

My questions are below:

1. Is it possible to to use **requests** to login Linkedin.com? I googled a lot and there is no example still useful today.
2. If possible, what's wrong with my code?
3. Except from csrf, did Linkedin.com use **other methods** to avoid web-scraping?

Thanks!

Comment: Progress bar? Maybe you need to wait a bit to login ;)

Comment: Now I decided to use selenium for this scrape task, selenium can wait the website loading itself, lol. Thanks for your kind advise!

Comment: I have the same question than you...
Did you find the solution ?
If yes, can you post it ?

If no, maybe it can help you :
https://towardsdatascience.com/using-browser-cookies-and-voyager-api-to-scrape-linkedin-via-python-25e4ae98d2a8
https://www.pythonf.cn/read/101431